# how do you distribute a number throughout a certain amount of fields?

Tags: python

Okay so lets say I have number , 100, and I want to split it up into 12 groups randomly and have the total from all the groups equate to 100. How would I do this, I have written a piece of code but it has a flaw.

```
from random import randint
total = 100
while total < 101:
    for i in range(0,9):
        num = randint(1,total)
        print(i,"|","*"*num)
        total -= num
if total <= 0:
    for j in range (i,10):
        print(j,"|","*"*total)
```

when you run it , once the total is equal to zero or less, it crashes, so it wont post the full results and I do not know how to deal fix this. I'm new to Python so my knowledge is limited.

Comment: What do you mean by crashes?  Do you mean the console just closes?

Comment: What do you mean by 'split a number into groups'??? Into addends, perhaps?

Comment: You should add error message to the question.

Comment: `while total < 101` is meaningless: You start with `total=100` and subtract positive numbers from it. It can never become bigger than it was before.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting a number *n* into *k* groups randomly is mathematically equivalent to randomly placing *k*-1 dividers. Thus, I would do something like this:

```
from random import randint
def split_randomly(n,k):
    dividers = set() # guarantee no duplicate dividers
    while len(dividers) < k-1:
        dividers.add(randint(1,n-1))
    dividers = [0] + sorted(dividers) + [n]
    return [dividers[i+1] - dividers[i] for i in range(len(dividers)-1)]
```

Comment: Note that I am still a bit unsure by what you mean by "groups". This code will return *k* numbers that add up to *n*, which seems to be what you mean

Comment: You actually _do_ have duplicate dividers, if it matters. I easily got `[4, 10, 8, 4, 15, 39, 3, 4, 8, 2, 2, 1]` and `[3, 1, 2, 20, 23, 1, 11, 8, 12, 3, 2, 14]`.

Comment: The dividers are not duplicates: the group sizes are duplicates (which wasn't part of the restriction if I'm not mistaken). I think my terminology was confusing. I'm treating the number line [0,*n*] as the full window, and I partition this window into *k* randomly-sized groups, which I do by placing *k*-1 dividers (which thus define *k* groups), and the sizes of the groups are *k* random numbers that must add up to *n*

Answer (score 0):

For a proper random split, you could use [**`random.sample`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). THe following gathers a sample of `k-1` random split points from [1..n] and `0` and `n` and returns a `list` of their pairwise differences:

```
from random import sample

def split(n, k):
  splits = [0] + sorted(sample(range(1, n), k-1)) + [n]
  return [end-start for start, end in zip(splits, splits[1:])]

>>> split(10, 7)
[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
>>> split(10, 7)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1]
>>> split(10, 7)
[1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]

>>> split(100, 12)
[10, 10, 8, 5, 7, 15, 1, 5, 1, 8, 26, 4]
```

Comment: This solution is equivalent to mine (but clearly much cleaner), but I'm curious to see how performance compares between yours calling `sample()` once vs. mine calling `randint()` *k*-1 times compares. I am guessing calling `sample()` once would be faster, so I think this is a superior solution to mine